# "System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid" - DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I am updating certain fields in my website, where I get the following error :

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

And the code where the error is this(as shown in the error message) :

> Line 77:                 productObj.QuantityInStock =
>   dt.Rows[0]["QuantityInStock"].ToString();
>
> Line 78:productObj.MinQuantity = dt.Rows[0]["MinQuantity"].ToString();
>
> Line 79:productObj.DateUpdated =(DateTime)dt.Rows[0]["DateUpdated"]; **//This is where error comes**
>
> Line 80:productObj.DateCreated = (DateTime)dt.Rows[0]["DateCreated"];
>
> Line 81: }

My update query is like this :

```
public int Update(Product obj)
        {
            string query = "update tblProduct set ProdName=@pname,ProdDescription=@pdesc,ProdSize=@psize,ProdPrice=@pprice,QuantityInStock=@qis,MinQuantity=@mq WHERE ProductID=@pid";

            List<SqlParameter> lstParams = new List<SqlParameter>();
            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@pid", obj.ProductID));
            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@pname", obj.ProdName));
            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@pprice", obj.ProdPrice));
            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@pdesc", obj.ProdDescription));
            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@psize", obj.ProdSize));
            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@qis", obj.QuantityInStock));
            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@mq", obj.MinQuantity));

            return DBUtility.ModifyData(query, lstParams);
        }
```

The **`Product`** class looks like this :

```
public class Product : IModel
    {
        public int ProductID;
        public string ProdName;
        public string ProdDescription;
        public string ProdSize;
        public string ProdPrice;
        public int CompanyID;
        public string ProdPhoto;
        public string QuantityInStock;
        public string MinQuantity;
        public int CategoryID;
        public DateTime DateCreated;
        public DateTime DateUpdated;
    }
```

**Error seems to be in this method :**

```
public Product SelectByID(int ID)
        {
            string query = "select * from tblProduct where ProductID=@pid";
            List<SqlParameter> lstParams = new List<SqlParameter>();
            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@pid", ID));

            DataTable dt = DBUtility.SelectData(query, lstParams);

            Product productObj = new Product();
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                productObj.ProdName = dt.Rows[0]["ProdName"].ToString();
                productObj.ProdDescription = dt.Rows[0]["ProdDescription"].ToString();
                productObj.CompanyID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["CompanyID"]);
                productObj.ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["ProductID"]);
                productObj.CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["CategoryID"]);
                productObj.ProdSize = dt.Rows[0]["ProdSize"].ToString();
                productObj.ProdPrice = dt.Rows[0]["ProdPrice"].ToString();
                productObj.QuantityInStock = dt.Rows[0]["QuantityInStock"].ToString();
                productObj.MinQuantity = dt.Rows[0]["MinQuantity"].ToString();
                productObj.DateUpdated = (DateTime)dt.Rows[0]["DateUpdated"]; //This where error comes
                productObj.DateCreated = (DateTime)dt.Rows[0]["DateCreated"];
            }

            return productObj;
        }
```

In my database too I have mentioned the *data-type* as **`DateTime`**, still why is this error coming ?

My method where I update looks like this :

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Product prodObj = new ProductLogic().SelectByID(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]));

            prodObj.ProdName = txtName.Text;
            prodObj.ProdPrice = txtPrice.Text;
            prodObj.ProdDescription = txtDesc.Text;
            prodObj.MinQuantity = txtMinQty.ToString();
            prodObj.QuantityInStock = txtInStock.ToString();
            prodObj.ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]); 

            int updateResult = new ProductLogic().Update(prodObj);

            if (updateResult > 0)
            {
                lblUpdateRes.Text = "Detail(s) updated successfully!";
                lblUpdateRes.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                lblUpdateRes.Text = "There was some error while updating your detail(s). Please try again later!";
                lblUpdateRes.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }

        }
```

Any ideas/suggestions ?

**EDIT : 1** Here is an image of my table :

[image]

Comment: Id `DateUpdated` a `DateTime` field in the database?  Could it be null?

Comment: You're missing the most important part. What does `tblProduct` look like?

Comment: Please post the value of `dt.Rows[0]["DateUpdated"]`

Comment: Yes that is **null** in the database , @DStanley

Comment: Is the error caused due to that ?

Comment: Try doing `(DateTime?)dt.Rows[0]["DateUpdated"]` (nullable date)

Comment: are you suggesting I should add **?** in the parenthesis ? @bradlis7

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh: Yes, it is. The value will be `DbNull.Value`, which can't be cast to `DateTime`. You should check for nullity and handle it appropriately.

Comment: @JonSkeet : Thank you Sir reverting and suggesting the error.. If only you could mention how should I handle the null value ?

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh: Well we don't know what you want to do with it. Maybe you should have a `DateTime?` property instead...

Comment: @JonSkeet : Using `DateTime?` throws an error saying : `Cannot implicitly convert 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh: Well yes, you've got to account for that change *everywhere* in your code... considering at each place where you use the property what you want to do if the value is null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88027/discussion-between-abhishek-ghosh-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: @JonSkeet : At all the places where I am trying to cast any `DateTime` ?

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh: Anywhere you're using this particular property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
productObj.DateUpdated = Convert.IsDBNull(dt.Rows[0]["DateUpdated"])? 
  DateTime.MinValue : (DateTime)dt.Rows[0]["DateUpdated"];
```

or, if `productObj.DateUpdated` is nullable `DateTime?`,

```
if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dt.Rows[0]["DateUpdated"]))
  productObj.DateUpdated.Value = (DateTime)dt.Rows[0]["DateUpdated"];
```

Comment: Conversion fails to DateTime.MinValue

Comment: I am getting this error : `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to data type int.` at the part where I get the result of the update query(which is an `int`)

Comment: how did you manage to get 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' into a database field?

Comment: I have not! I am bewildered to why i am getting this error !

Comment: Please look at my edited question! I have added a screenshot of my table! and you can see I have correctly mentioned the type as `datetime`.. The error occurs when I get the result of the update query into an integer :/ and I do not understand why that error comes ! Please help!

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh - you are using `txtMinQty.ToString();` and `txtInStock.ToString();` to assign two `prodObj` fields. These `ToString()` calls produce "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox" which is written to the database. QuantityInStock and MinQuantity fields should be integers as their corresponding columns in the database.

Comment: thanks a ton!!! I did not see that at all! Very silly of me thanks so much again!!!

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime` cannot be null in .NET.  If your database can have null values then you can either change the type of `DateUpdated` to a nullable date/time (`DateTime?`):

```
productObj.DateUpdated = (DateTime?)(dt.Rows[0]["DateUpdated"] == DBNull.Value ? null : dt.Rows[0]["DateUpdated"]);
```

or use a "magic" value to represent null:

```
productObj.DateUpdated = (DateTime)(dt.Rows[0]["DateUpdated"] == DBNull.Value ? DateTime.MinValue : dt.Rows[0]["DateUpdated"]);
```

Comment: what will `DateTime.MinValue` return ?

Comment: As you can see the `DateUpdated` can only have a value when the fields are updated.. So I need to have no value or the date time when the record  was updated .. ?

Comment: [DateTime.MinValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx) is the earliest date supported by `DateTime` - namely `Jan 1, 0001`

Comment: If you can change `DateUpdated` to a `DateTime?` thn you can set it to null.  `DateTime` cannot have "no value".

Comment: I show a custom message when there is null value in that column ? So i cannot show `Jan 1, 0001`

Comment: As you have edited the answer.. When DBNull.Value is true and is `null` then will the cast be correct ?

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh To `DateTime?` yes, not to `DateTime` as it cannot be `null`

Comment: I am getting an error when I add a **`?`** in the paranthesis ?

Comment: I still get a null reference exception using that code

Comment: Using `DateTime?` throws an error saying : `Cannot implicitly convert 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: You need to change the _type_ of the `DateCreated` field to `DateTime?` if you want it to store null values (`public DateTime? DateCreated;`)

Comment: Okkay let me try that Sir!

Comment: I am getting this error : `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to data type int.` at the part where I get the result of the update query(which is an `int`)

Comment: Use `.Text` instead of `.ToString()`

Comment: I have not used `.ToString()` anywhere with DateTime ?

Comment: Please look at my edited question! I have added a screenshot of my table! and you can see I have correctly mentioned the type as `datetime`.. The error occurs when I get the result of the update query into an integer :/ and I do not understand why that error comes ! Please help!

Comment: Please stop suggesting magic values when  parsing values. TryParse, TryParse, TryParse!!!